# How do I search for channel names in WeeChat?

Tags: irc, weechat

In the IRC client XChat, it is possible to search for a list of channels in the current connected network. For example, searching for the keyword "python" using Server → Network List on the Freenode network lists all channels that have python in their name.

Is such a search functionality also possible in Weechat? If so, how can I search for a channel?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the `/list` command... the standard IRC command for listing and searching IRC channels.
You can add a regular expression at the end to search for specific chans.

You can use the `/list -re <regex>` option to search with regex.

If you need more info, use the `/help` command; and learn more about real irc functionality (instead of relying on GUI wrappers).

Comment: Is there a way to order the list by users, or search it, or open it in another windows? kinda hard to manage all those channels outputted

Comment: @HarryMoreno look at the listbuffer script for weechat

Answer (score 10):

WeeChat doesn't have a channel search feature, as far as I know. But however, you can use the `ALIS` (Advanced LIsting Service) channel bot (on freenode):

To search for channels containing `python` in their channel name:

```
/msg alis list *python*
```

To search for a channel whose topic contains the word `foo`:

```
/msg alis list * -topic *python*
```

(the wildcards are required)

For other options, see:

```
/msg alis help list
```

`/list` works too, but on a big network like freenode (with over 40 thousand channels), it may flood your client off with the results or produce unexpected results.

**Note:** This is a network specific feature of freenode, and is client-independent. It can be used from any IRC client.

Comment: While there *is* a search function in weechat, this might be useful for freenode users...

Comment: This is much better, as the `/list` keyword returns the entire list of channels.

Comment: @demure describes the best way to do this, however I wanted to point out that you can search any buffer with <Ctrl-r>.  So you "could" /list all the channels, then <Ctrl-r> and search through the entire list if you wanted, then <up/down> arrow to navigate the matches.